# How to loop through a set of checkboxes and making each set independent of each other in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm building a pizza menu app in Vue.js. If a user buys 3 of the same size pizza, then I need to display the toppings they want to add for each pizza. 
The problem is when I click on a checkbox for pizza-3, it jumps up a checks that topping on pizza-1. 
For some reason, I can't get the set of toppings (checkboxes), independent of one another. I'm having trouble figuring this one out. Please help.

```
<div v-for="n in Number(quantity)">
   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
            :data-target="'#collapse' +n" aria-expanded="false" aria- 
             controls="collapseExample">
                    Add Toppings for <b>Pizza - {{n}}</b>
  </button>
<div class="collapse.show" :id="'#collapse' +n">
   <div class="card card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div v-for="category in categories" class="col">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th><h4><b>{{category.name}}</b></h4></th>
             </tr>
             <tr v-for="name in category.topping_items">
                <td>
                  <input type="checkbox" v-model="selected" :value="name.item 
                          + '-pizza-' + n " :id="name.id + n" />
                  <label :class="{bold_name: name.double_price}" 
                          :for="name.id + n">{{name.item}}</label>
                 </td>

               </tr>
             </table>
           </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="align-content-center">
        <button @click="closeForm">Add Selected Toppings</button>
     </div>

<script>
export default {
    name: "AddToppings",
    props:['item', 'quantity'],
    data(){
        return{
            selected:[]
        }
    },
    created(){

    },
    computed:{
        categories(){
            return this.$store.state.cat_toppings;
        }
    },
    methods:{
        cancelCatDelete(){
            $('#addToppings').modal('hide')
        },
        closeForm(){
            //console.log('cart', this.item);
            $('#addToppings').modal('hide');
            this.item.toppings.push(this.selected);
            this.$store.dispatch('addItemToCart', this.item);

            this.selected = [];
            this.$emit('form_closed');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your code.

Here are the major things that changed:

- The `selected` data property is changed to object so that it can handle multiple arrays of selected toppings based on the category.
- A `watcher` for the `categories` is added which will react everytime the category is changed. So for example, if you added a new category into your store, the `selected` data property will add new array entries for each new category that was added.
- We used `this.$set()` to add new entry to your `selected` object. This is crucial for keeping everything reactive, specially to object properties or arrays that are dynamically added.
- We updated the `v-model` mapping for the checkbox into `v-model="selected[category.name]"`
- Lastly, we can now loop the `selected` to retrieve the selected toppings for each category

like this:

```
this.selected.forEach((selected, category_name) => {
    this.item.toppings.push(selected);
});
```

See the fully updated code below:

```js
export default {
  name: "AddToppings",
  props: ['item', 'quantity'],
  data() {
    return {
      selected: {}
    }
  },
  created() {

  },
  computed: {
    categories() {
      return this.$store.state.cat_toppings;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    categories: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(categories) {
        categories.forEach((category) => {
          if (this.selected[category.name] == undefined) {
            this.$set(this.selected, category.name, []);
          }
        })
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    cancelCatDelete() {
      $('#addToppings').modal('hide')
    },
    closeForm() {
      //console.log('cart', this.item);
      $('#addToppings').modal('hide');
      this.selected.forEach((selected, category_name) => {
        this.item.toppings.push(selected);
      });
      this.$store.dispatch('addItemToCart', this.item);

      this.selected = [];
      this.$emit('form_closed');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div v-for="n in Number(quantity)">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" :data-target="'#collapse' +n" aria-expanded="false" aria- controls="collapseExample">
                    Add Toppings for <b>Pizza - {{n}}</b>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse.show" :id="'#collapse' +n">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div v-for="category in categories" class="col">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <h4><b>{{category.name}}</b></h4>
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="name in category.topping_items">
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" v-model="selected[category.name]" :value="name.item 
                          + '-pizza-' + n " :id="name.id + n" />
                <label :class="{bold_name: name.double_price}" :for="name.id + n">{{name.item}}</label>
              </td>

            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="align-content-center">
  <button @click="closeForm">Add Selected Toppings</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for being so comprehensive with explaining the solution to my problem. There's no way I would've been able to figure this one out on my own. I appreciate you taking the time with helping me out.

Comment: Sure no problem. Is this the answer you are looking for?

Comment: Actually, it didn't work, and I'm still having the same problem as before. But, I'm building on the concept that you introduced. I'm feeding off the direction that you've given me. Despite it not working, I still appreciate your efforts in helping me out.

Comment: Sure no problem